# Allowing api requests (ajax) while logged in in rundeck

Tags: api, rundeck

My team has been migrating the old rundeck 1.6.6 to  3.1.2.

Besides Rundeck, we also have a lot of web interfaces that query (Ajax) rundeck's API.
That used to work because we just needed to be logged in to rundeck.

It doesn't work anymore! (as you might have guessed)

There is a need for the user to be connected to order handle his access roles (what he can and cannot do).

I saw a mention that this feature was disallowed by default, but i cannot find anywhere which option to change in order to reallow it again.

Do you guys have an idea please?

Comment: Hi Nuno, what feature do you mean? The Rundeck GUI has an internal no versioned API calls for GUI use (maybe the "Ajax API" that you mean), not to expose to use as "real API". To access Rundeck data and functions you must to use Rundeck API: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html or RD CLI tool: https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/ Greetings!

Comment: Hello, thank you. 

I'm talking about the http api endpoints. 
The old version of Rundeck (which is still in our production) allows for the http api endpoints to be called if the user is logged in first. And the query would fail if the user is not logged in. 

I just tested it it. But the new version does not allow it. 

gschueler said in 2017 _"do you mean you are entering the API url in your browser? by default, rundeck disables API access if you log in through a web browser"_. 

It gives me hope that there is an option that i only have to enable somehow

thank you

Comment: Can you try adding this line at rundeck-config.properties file: rundeck.security.apiCookieAccess.enabled=true and then restart Rundeck?

Comment: yeah, thank you, i know that one, it's enabled on my conf. 
But that's just to establish an authentication via cookies instead of token. I don't think it's about the gui login.

Comment: i was able to do the j_security_check via ajax, which it works, but it actually also logsin the user at the GUI side, so the query i want to do fails because i'm logged in.

Comment: the original interdiction was created here: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/pull/909/commits/5ccd6e72cecabf28f7e57422bb283d7bc7ba29d3#diff-8556ea4f697ea545a1905e005f26d877

i believe the current bit of code is here: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/blob/master/rundeckapp/grails-app/controllers/rundeck/interceptors/ApiAccessInterceptor.groovy

If i am right, i am hoping this can be set with an option somehow. I really would like to avoid getting the sources

Comment: i found the opcode iconst_0 (03) in the ApiAccessInterceptor.class, change it to iconst_1 (04), updated the war, and now everything is working... so far

Comment: Amazing Nuno. Post it as an answer, maybe helps another person. Cheers!